# Counting functions satisfying $f(j)<f(i)+j-i$ for all $i<j$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Ques : Let $N$ be the number of functions $f: \{1, 2, 3,\dots, 2018\} \to \{1, 2, 3,\dots, 2018\}$ satisfying $f(j) < f (i) + j - i$ for all integers $i,j$ such that $1 \leq i < j \leq 2018$.  Find $N$.

My development so far : difference of elements' value in domain is strictly greater than that in Co domain. Hence every consecutive number should be mapped to a lesser or equal number the previous number is mapped to. Hence the function should be non-strictly decreasing.

Comment: Check again : lesser or less than or equal to? Nonincreasing vs decreasing.

Comment: Reserve the word "*permutations*" to talk *only* about bijective functions from a set to itself.  This question has nothing to do with permutations and so it should never have been mentioned.

Comment: Try proving that $f(j)<f(i)+j-i$ for all $i,j$ such that $1\leq i<j\leq 2018$ is true if and only if $f(j)\leq f(i)$ for all $i,j$ such that $1\leq i<j\leq 2018$.  So, you are simply counting the number of monotonic (*non-strict*) decreasing functions.  This should be a problem type you've seen before.

Comment: As for "nonincreasing" vs "decreasing"... I dislike the term "nonincreasing."  It can be interpreted as the negation of "increasing" meaning simply that there is *at least one* point where it decreases but possibly others where it increases... not that it always decreases.  The condition that $f(j)\leq f(i)$ for all $i,j$ such that $i<j$ is better said as "non-strictly decreasing" in my opinion while the condition that $f(j)<f(i)$ for all $i<j$ is better said as "strictly decreasing."

Comment: $f(1) < f(2008) - 2007 \le 1$. $f(2) < f(2008) - 2006 \le 2$. etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz How did you concluded that $f(j)\leq f(i)$. I think inequality must be strict i.e. $f(j)<f(i)$. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @mathophile consider for example $f$ a constant function. Isn't it true that such an $f$ satisfies $f(j)<f(i)+j-i$ whenever $i<j$ despite the comparison of $f(j)$ and $f(i)$ not being strict?

Comment: @mathophile Further, it is worth noting that there exists exactly one strictly increasing function $[n]\to[n]$... the identity function.  Similarly exactly one strictly decreasing function.  That would have made the problem terribly uninteresting